How can I convert a whitespace separated string to integers in rust
I'm trying to convert a string example "12 34 56" into a vector of integers using Rust. I tried using .chunks() and a few other things the code I used works as expected for "123456" but both strings have the same output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5] I'm trying to get [12, 34, 56]
fn to_vector(s: &str) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut digits = Vec::new();
    for c in s.chars() {
        if let Some(digit) =c.to_digit(10) {
            digits.push(digit);
        }
    }
    digits
}
fn main() {
    let my_string = "12 34 45";
    let my_vec = to_vector(my_string);
    
    println!("{:?}", my_vec);
}


str::split_whitespace?

You can achieve this by splitting the string by whitespace delimiters and applying parsing function on the result
use std::str::FromStr;

fn to_vector<T: FromStr>(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<T>, <T as FromStr>::Err> {
    s.split_ascii_whitespace().map(str::parse::<T>).collect()
}

fn to_vector_filtered<T: FromStr>(s: &str) -> Vec<T> {
    s.split_ascii_whitespace()
        .filter_map(|e| str::parse::<T>(e).ok())
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let my_string = "12 34 45";
    let my_vec = to_vector::<u32>(my_string);

    println!("{:?}", my_vec);

    let my_bad_string = "12 hello 45";
    let my_vec = to_vector_filtered::<usize>(my_bad_string);
    println!("{:?}", my_vec);
}

two versions, depending on whether you want to deal with parsing errors or  to ignore them.
